# Jaxb XML Attribute

Tags: java, jaxb

I am doing marshalling of java object to XML using JAXB . I had requirement to create some thing like

`<link rel="self" href="test" />`

How this can be done? what annotations should i use.

Any help will be greatly appriciated

Java Class

```
public class Item {

    private String title;
    private int price;

    private String productLink;
    private String rel;

    public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
    return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
    }

    @XmlPath("link/@href")
    public String getProductLink() {
    return productLink;
    }

    public void setProductLink(String productLink) {
    this.productLink = productLink;
    }
```

Comment: This is not valid XML.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib - looks valid to me

Comment: did you try reading a jaxb tutorial?

Comment: @ jtahlborn thanks for the suggestion, i need it urgently thats why i posted

Comment: sorry, the rest of the world isn't going to do your job for you, no matter how "urgent" it is for you.

Comment: @jtahlborn I am putting my efforts to get it , Hope i will get it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Link` class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` with to properties (`rel` and `href`) that are annotated with `@XmlAttribute`.

The following tutorial will help get you acquainted with [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222):

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

---

**OPTION #1 - Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) as your JAXB Provider**

Using the `@XmlPath` extension in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) you could do the following:

```
@XmlPath("link[@rel='self']/@href")
public String getProductLink() {
    return productLink;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

---

**OPTION #2 - Using an JAXB Provider**

You could use an `XmlAdapter`

```
@XmlElement(name="link")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LinkAdapter.class)
public String getProductLink() {
    return productLink;
}
```

***LinkAdapter***

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class LinkAdapter extends XmlAdapter<LinkAdapter.Link, String>{

    public static class Link {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String rel = "self";

        @XmlAttribute
        public String href;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(Link v) throws Exception {
        return v.href;
    }

    @Override
    public Link marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        Link link = new Link();
        link.href = v;
        return link;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind response, isn't possible some thing like  @XmlPath("link/@href"). I did'nt understand how to give 'rel' as well to the same path

Comment: @user964147 - There are many ways to map this.  Could you update your question to include the class structure you are trying to map this XML to?

Comment: Thanks a lot fro your response